# Volley request inside recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am using Volley image request inside recyclerview adapter.
Request appears to work fine until a fast scroll is done, whenever I scroll the recyclerview fast up or down, the app crashes with following error :

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env: Failed anonymous mmap(0x0, 8192, 0x3, 0x22, -1, 0): Permission denied. See process maps in the log.
    at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:883)
    at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:134)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:91)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:67)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:102)
    at com.squadtechs.hdwallpapercollection.main_activity.fragment.WallpaperAdapter.populateViews(WallpaperAdapter.kt:60)
    at com.squadtechs.hdwallpapercollection.main_activity.fragment.WallpaperAdapter.onBindViewHolder(WallpaperAdapter.kt:38)
    at com.squadtechs.hdwallpapercollection.main_activity.fragment.WallpaperAdapter.onBindViewHolder(WallpaperAdapter.kt:21)
```

Following is my `onBindViewHolder()` code:

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WallpaperHolder, position: Int) {
    populateViews(holder, position)
}

private fun populateViews(holder: WallpaperHolder, position: Int) {
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
    val imageRequest = ImageRequest(
        list[position].wallpaper_image_url,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            holder.imgGrid.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER
            holder.imgGrid.setImageBitmap(response)
            holder.progress.visibility = View.GONE
        },
        1024,
        860,
        ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER,
        null,
        Response.ErrorListener { error ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            holder.progress.visibility = View.GONE
        }).setRetryPolicy(
        DefaultRetryPolicy(
            20000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
        )
    )
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest)
    holder.txtCategory.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

According to log, error is thrown at line where request queue is declared, i.e `val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)`

**Remember: the app works fine when scroled normally but crashes when scrolled fast**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recycler view will fire your adapter's `onBindViewHolder` every time an element is supposed to be displayed that was not bound to a view before (or that was un-bound).

When you scroll fast, binds and unbinds will happen fast. Each bind generates an HTTP request, which is a relatively expensive IO operation that consumes memory.

This is a recipe for disaster. Do not send HTTP requests based on a regular user interaction like this. If someone keeps scrolling up and down, the app is guaranteed to run out of memory.

Instead, think of a better strategy. Possibly pre-load data asynchronously, or at least cache data once loaded.

Answer (score 1):

@fjc pointed out correct the HTTP request is resource intensive. If you look at your `populateViews` function's first line

```
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
```

This is the main reason of OOM. You are creating multiple request queue for each image request which is therefore occupying all the resources thus result in OOM. In order to overcome that you need to use a single requestqueue for all of your application. it is also recommended by Google to use a Singleton class for handling the requestqueue.[DOC](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton)

> if your application makes constant use of the network, it's probably
>   most efficient to set up a single instance of RequestQueue that will
>   last the lifetime of your app. You can achieve this in various ways.
>   The recommended approach is to implement a singleton class that
>   encapsulates RequestQueue and other Volley functionality. Another
>   approach is to subclass Application and set up the RequestQueue in
>   Application.onCreate(). But this approach is discouraged; a static
>   singleton can provide the same functionality in a more modular way.

A quick way to solve your problem is to copy the following class in your project

```
class MySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: MySingleton? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: MySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }
    val imageLoader: ImageLoader by lazy {
        ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                object : ImageLoader.ImageCache {
                    private val cache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20)
                    override fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap {
                        return cache.get(url)
                    }
                    override fun putBitmap(url: String, bitmap: Bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap)
                    }
                })
    }
    val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
    }
    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

Replace the first line of your populateViews function with

```
val requestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(context).requestQueue
```

This should solve your problem

Another way is to use [NetworkImageView](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) from Volley's ToolBox

How to use
Replace your ImageView with NetworkImageView

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            />
```

and load the image using

```
holder.imgGrid.setImageUrl(list[position].wallpaper_image_url,MySingleton.getInstance(context).imageLoader);
```